# Make same changes to multiple git repositories

Tags: git, git-fork

We have a Dll with multiple versions. Each one needs to be supported separately as it is sold as a separate product. In some cases, bug fixes apply to multiple versions of the Dll. Previously, TFS was used. A changeset made to TB_2020 and TB_2021 would be created in TB_2020, merged up to TB_Mainline, and merged down to TB_2021.

...,
TB_2019,
TB_2020,
TB_2021,
TB_Mainline

We are transitioning over to git. We would like to use separate, forked repositories. Pushing a commit from TB_2020 to the remote TB_Mainline using force pushes all changes, not just that specific commit. Is what we want possible? If so, how could it be done?

Comment: Sounds like you should have a single repo with one branch for each product.

Comment: I was hoping we could used separate repos  to avoid having separate products in the same repository. It sounds like that isn't going to work based on how git works. Should I delete this question since it doesn't have an answer?

Comment: I don't see why; it could still be useful for others with the same requirements. (I don't see why you would want separate repos if the products share code, though arguably a better design might be to isolate the shared functionality into a separate library, and then have simpler repos which each build a separate particular flow for that library.)